# in Rack middleware how to ignore default headers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, rack

I want to use this `request = Rack::Request.new(env)` to log the headers present in `request.env`, but the issue here is it will not only consist of the `additional headers` we are passing, but it also consists of default headers, how to ignore it and only print the `additional headers`?

Comment: What headers do you consider to be default headers, and what are additional headers? Is `Authorization` default or additional? What about `Forwarded-For`? `Content-Type`?

Comment: @spickermann Actually in this `request.env` how exactly i can access the `headers`?, i want only the headers i will be passing during calling any API.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. `request.env` will return the headers. Or if you are interested in a particular header, then you can call `request.get_header('HEADER_OF_INTEREST')`.

Comment: i want to exclude the access headers that are getting added related to `puma` related, some `HTTP` ones, `action_dispatch`  many more, so what i wanted to do is if any request is calling api in my service i want to log the `request headers, request body, and request parameters` they are passing with that request.

Comment: How is `Rack::Request` supposed to know what headers puma added, a proxy on the way between the client and the server, you added, or the client's browser added? You can of course exclude some well-known headers (e.g. [`Rack::Headers::KNOWN_HEADERS`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/main/lib/rack/headers.rb#L9)), but it is not guaranteed that such a list covers all unwanted headers and excludes all headers that might be of interest for you. Best would be that you maintain a list of headers that are important for your use case.

Comment: but is there any other way than `Rack` which can help me in logging the necessary headers? like i have explored `ActionDispatch::Request`, `SemanticLogger` which were not of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read and log HTTP header in Ruby on Rails, there is no middleware or gem required. Because access to the headers and a logger is already included to Rails.

I would add a small `before_action` to the `application_controller.rb` to add a specific header I am interested in like this:

```
# in app/controllers/application_controller.rb
before_filer :log_headers

private

def log_headers
  Rails.looger.info "My API key: #{request.headers['MY-API-KEY']}"
end
```

Or you can log all headers, except some, like this:

```
def log_headers
  headers_to_exclude = ['FOO', 'BAR']
  headers_of_interest = request.headers.env.except(*headers_to_exclude)

  Rails.looger.info "headers: #{headers_of_interest}"
end
```

Or you can only log headers explicitly named, like this:

```
def log_headers
  headers_to_include = ['FOO', 'BAR']
  headers_of_interest = request.headers.env.slice(*headers_to_include)

  Rails.looger.info "headers: #{headers_of_interest}"
end
```

The list of headers to include or exclude could be extracted into a constant and the logic could be placed into a concern.